# How to send message to a specific client with socket.io if the application uses the cluster up and running in several processes on different ports?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

The application starts in cluster mode, each worker is to establish a connection to the socket, using redis adapter:

```
app.set('port', httpPort);
    let server = http.createServer(app);
    let io = require('./socketServer')(server);
    io.adapter(redis({host: host, port: port}));
app.set('io', io);
```

then we connect the main socket.io file (socketServer), where after authorization of the socket and on.connection event, we save sessionID in variable socketID, and store current socket connection in array `io.clients`

```
io.sockets.on('connection', (socket) =>{
        var socketID = socket.handshake.user.sid;     
        io.clients[socketID] = socket;
        io.clients[socketID].broadcast.emit('loggedIn',socket.handshake.user.data);

        socket.on('disconnect', () =>{
            delete io.clients[socketID];
        });
});
```

Before nodejs app, we have nginx with customized "upstream" to organize a "sticky sessions" (http://socket.io/docs/using-multiple-nodes/#nginx-configuration).
Then, when we want to send a message to a particular customer, already from the controller we get id user, and get session-id for id (we pre-authorization keep these correspondences in redis), and then just send a message:

```
this.redis.getByMask(`sid_clients:*`,(err,rdbData) =>{
            Async.each(clients,(client,next)=>{
                let sid = `sid_clients:${client}`;
                let currentClient = rdbData[sid];
                if(!currentClient || !this.io.clients[currentClient]) return next();
                this.io.clients[currentClient].emit(event,data);
                return next();
});
```

It works fine when we run the application in a single process. But this don't work when running in a cluster mode. Connection message  "loggedIn" is send to  all customers on all processes. But if a single process to send a message to the client that connects to a server in another process - does not work, because that each process has own array `io.clients` and they are always have different content, so the message does not can reach the right customer.

So, how send events to the specific client in a cluster mode? How to keep all connected sockets in one place to avoid situations such as mine?

Comment: Hey man did you find the answer? I'm looking for this too

Comment: @MiltonFilho, use `io.to` with rooms